# Is there a Perl or Lua alternative to Capistrano?

Tags: perl, lua, capistrano, web-deployment, automated-deploy

For a number of web-applications I need something like Capistrano to automate deployment. I know Capistrano can be used to deploy non-ruby applications but I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I expect writing deployment configurations can be a bit of a pain.

So I was wondering, are there any alternatives to Capistrano written in either Perl of Lua?

Also, forgot to mention, the platform running the deployments is Windows (XP). So Capistrano is already more or less out of the question. Although I found out it can run with the MINGW32 Bash shell that comes with Git for Windows.

Comment: Just learn Ruby. It's not that hard and you don't need to know that much to use Capistrano.

Comment: I gave Capistrano a go but it doesn't integrate nicely on Windows. Maybe I should give it another try.

Comment: Gave it another go today but it's really troublesome on Windows. Also found a post of the (original?) developer stating he doesn't care if it runs on Windows or not. So Capistrano is out of the question for me since running a VPS only for deploying applications is not a viable solution at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure there is an exact Perl "clone" of Capistrano.

However on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) there are these Make / Rake like tools:

- [`App::PPBuild`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-PPBuild/)  (no longer available on CPAN, it can be found on [BackPan](http://backpan.perl.org) in [EXODIST folder](http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/E/EX/EXODIST/))
- [`Pake`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/pake/)

And these SSH tools:

- [`SSH::Command`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SSH-Command/)
- [`SSH::RPC`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SSH-RPC/)
- [`Net::OpenSSH`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenSSH/)
- [`Net::SSH`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH/)
- [`Net::SSH::Perl`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/)

So combination of these should fit the bill.

PS. Regarding your update - Net::SSH::Perl maybe useful if you don't have SSH installed on machine (this is pure Perl SSH implementation).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I can create something usable with App::PPBuild and Net::SSH (or Net::SSH::Perl).

A nice feature about Capistrano is that you can manage multiple servers at the same time. Although cool, it's not a feature I need now or in the future.

App::PPBuild is no Capistrano so I'll let this one open for a bit longer before clicking the answered button. Hoping that a full fledged solution is available.

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl just hangs on the command line in Windows. Tried installing it with cpan and ppm but once I try to setup a connection it just hangs.

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl works here for me (on Mac though)... though it wasn't without its hiccups!  If you still having problems with it then might be best to post a new question. Alternatively you may find installing SSH and using one of the other modules a better option.

Comment: Although I stated above a VPS wouldn't a viable solution for us it is the way we're going now anyway (we've got some server resources left). So I'll be running Capistrano and there's no longer a need for an alternative.

Comment: These days a viable Perl alternative for Capistrano does exist in the form of Rex (http://rexify.org).

Comment: @Htbaa Yep.  I have mentioned Rex in another SO answer.  I should have updated it here long ago but I won't now that `Olivier D` answer covers Rex.   See `Is there anything like Fabric for Perl?` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281836/is-there-anything-like-fabric-for-perl/7288678#7288678

Answer (score 8):

The Perl alternative is [Rex](http://rexify.org/). And it has way more features than capistrano.