# Is there anything like Fabric for Perl?

Tags: perl, deployment, fabric

I really like [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/) for personal projects, but I am working in a Perl-oriented environment in my day-to-day job.  I’d like to stay away from introducing another language to the workflow, so I’m wondering if there exists something similar to Fabric for doing automated deployments in Perl.

Comment: Could you describe the features you need? Just in case there is no direct translation of the fabric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Rex](http://rexify.org/).  However its more based on [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) than [Fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Also check out this older SO question [Is there a Perl or Lua alternative to Capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832101/is-there-a-perl-or-lua-alternative-to-capistrano)

Answer (score -1):

As noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666392/php-alternative-for-pythons-fabric/4670514#4670514) if you can log in with SSH, you can use Fabric, no matter the language used in the running app. Unless there is some Perl specific code that can't be run by issuing a command in a shell.

Comment: I am well aware that I running Fabric does not correlate in any way to the application to be deployed.  Yet, as I stated, the environment is mostly Perl, so I’d like to stick to that.